# If A is an invertible matrix, its row echelon form A' is an identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I was going through Artin's Algebra and in Theorem 1.2.21 on Square Systems, Artin states that if A is an invertible Square matrix, then its row echelon form A' is an identity matrix. How does one arrive at that conclusion? Can anyone provide a proof of the statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are talking about the row reduced form. I think you only need to establish that $A's$ row reduced form will not have a zero row. Think along the lines of determinant and elementary matrices. So each row's leading coefficient is $1$ all lined up along the diagonal and the other elements in the column are all $0$, which is precisely the identity matrix.

Comment: This is one of those things it’s best to try to persuade yourself is plausible with a couple specific examples first, before trying to understand the fully general theorem. Work through solving systems of the form $Ax = b$ with an augmented matrix $[A | b]$ and see what happens when $A$ is or is not invertible, respectively. Any Algebra II or Precalculus textbook should have plenty of exercises with solutions to work through.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Form the $n\times 2n$  augmented matrix $[A|I]$ and row reduce it to reduced row echelon form using elementary matrices:
$$E_k\cdots E_1\cdot [A|I]=[A'|B]$$

Now, either $A'$ is $I$ or $A'$ is not $I$.

If $A'$ is not $I$, then there must be at least one zero row in $A'$, or in other words, there are strictly less than $n$ pivotal columns in $A'$. This means that $A'$ is not invertible, by rank-nullity. Since $A$ and $A'$ are row equivalent, then $A$ is not invertible.

If $A'=I$, then we have $$E_k\cdots E_1\cdot A= I\text{ and }E_k\cdots E_1\cdot I=B$$Since each elementary matrix is invertible, and the product of invertible matrices is invertible, then $B$ is invertible. Now, we get that $BA=I$, which implies that $A$ is invertible.

If $A$ is invertible, then we cannot have the first case, so we must have the second case.